# Converting 1 row instance to a suitable format in R for repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I'm really struggling with how to format my data to a suitable one in R.

At the moment, I have my data in the format of:

```
ParticipantNo | Sex | Age | IV1(0)_IV2(0)_DV1 | IV1(1)_IV2(0)_DV1 | etc
```

There are two levels for `IV1`, and 3 for `IV2`, so 6 columns per DV.

I've stacked them, so that I compare all `IV1` results with each other, and the same for `IV2` using a Friedman test.

However, I'd like to compare across groups like Sex and Age, and was told ANOVA is the best for this. I've used ANOVA directly before in SPSS, which accepts this data format.

The problem I have is getting this data into the correct format in R.

As I understand it, it should look like:

```
1 | M | 40 | IV1(0)_IV2(0)_DV1_Result

1 | M | 40 | IV1(1)_IV2(0)_DV1_Result

1 | M | 40 | IV1(0)_IV2(1)_DV1_Result

1 | M | 40 | IV1(1)_IV2(1)_DV1_Result

1 | M | 40 | IV1(0)_IV2(2)_DV1_Result

1 | M | 40 | IV1(1)_IV2(2)_DV1_Result
```

Then I can do 
`aov(sex~DV1_result, data=data)`

Does this seem like the correct thing to do, and if so, how can I convert from the format I have to the one I need in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I used `stack` on my data, and then `separate` (i.e. `s = separate(stack(data), "ind", c("IV1", "IV2")`.

Then I could do the ANOVA by `aov(values ~ IV1 * IV2, data = s)`

Hope this helps someone!